# var/session/ session files are empty

Tags: cache, session

We have a weird problem. On a site at random times the sessions files on the site are empty, 0 kb.
After removing/clearing the cache the sessions get back to about 2.2kb.

I have no clue to figure out what is the trigger when this happens.

On the times the session are empty no one can login or add stuff to cart. The admin login also doesn't appear to work at those times.

Does anybody have an idea?

Session files are stored in /var/session/
It's Magento 1.7.0.0
The Google bot is also quite bussy indexing.
The server is in our controll and run 3 other shops without problems.
At launch we didn't have this problem. When it started there where no files edited in a few weeks prior. And the changes where mostly templating

**How we solved it, sort of...**
we moved to an other host, no problems there.

Comment: How many disc free space do you have on your server?

Comment: at least 5 gig. The user is over it's limit but not suspended. An other user who is also over the limit and not suspended does not have this problem.

Comment: Why are you not saving session in database ?

Comment: no particular reason. Is that better? If so can you name a source?

Comment: I wouldn't jump to saving sessions in the database. This can add to an already busy database server with additional queries. There is nothing wrong with storing sessions in the filesystem.

This issue sounds like the user that runs as the webserver is over quota. Does a repquota -a and repquota-ag reveal anything? I assume permissions on var/session are fine?

Comment: @RobMangiafico The quota was increased some time ago. the permissions are `drwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Did you ever find an solution to this? I'm having the same problem with v1.9.2.1, switching to db, memcache or redis does solve the issue. I started having problems after I upgraded to PHP 5.6, it worked fine on 5.5 for some reason.

Comment: Hello @javiervd,  No we didn't find a real solution to this. Like I said we moved the shop. Never saw the issue after that. Are you 100% sure core Magento is unchanged? Try turning modules off one by one to check if this helps.

Comment: @janw 100% sure, it's clean magento install, what I ended un noticing is that the PHP user was running as "www-user" and the var/session folder was created using "www-data" (default apache user) so I changed the PHP user to "www-data" and it's working fine now. Still it's strange that even setting the folder permissions to 777 it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Move your sessions in the memcached.
It's saving sessions in memory, so it's working faster than from filesystem. Also you will have ability use few servers instead one.
Memcached has one issue. When server reboots - users will lose their sessions.
More information here: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-session-storage-which-to-choose-and-why/